# What is the best js/jquery Cropper(picture) available up to 2016 with photo resize and shape cropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wanted to implement photo cropper into one of my project, and I found [fengyuanchen jQuery cropper plugin](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to be a good choice. But I am open to any other suggestion that can give my user the best experience.

This is the link for fengyuanchen's plug-in: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Please suggest.

Comment: http://codecanyon.stbeets.nl/ //use this one of the best photo editor / cropper ive seen

Comment: Hi Vishnu, its better than fengyuanchen? I will try it out now

Comment: u can compare both plugins fetaures and decide which is better as per your requirement

Comment: Tried it out, but the fengyuanchen's support scolling zoom in and out, so I think its better in term of user experience

Comment: You might also be interested in [Doka.js](https://pqina.nl/doka/), cropperjs is a great choice but I feel Doka offers a better mobile experience. Disclaimer, I'm the author.